# Delay affecting the rest of the instructions

Tags: java, delay

I added a 5 seconds delay into my java code and I met a problem. This is my code:

```
protected void createAccountButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (verifyData()){
            addUserData();
            validCont.setText("Message.");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            backToLoginButton(event);
        }
    }
```

Since I added `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);` to my code, the message isn't displayed anymore. The rest of instructions works corectly. I have the same problem with `Thread.sleep();`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sleeping on the EDT (event dispatching thread). You can fix this by running this routine in another thread, or with a SwingWorker